# How to write tabs using Reportlab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I'm trying to use Reportlab (python 3.5.2) to write some text and figures to a PDF, but it seems the tab character is not recognized, it gets printed as a black square.
The code below reproduces this issue.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def tabs_reportlab():
    my_canvas = canvas.Canvas("tab_test.pdf",
                              pagesize=letter)

    textobject = my_canvas.beginText()

    textobject.setTextOrigin(10, 730)
    textobject.setFont('Times-Roman', 12)
    textobject.textLine(text='A tab between each    word.')

    my_canvas.drawText(textobject);

    my_canvas.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tabs_reportlab()
```

It gets printed as:

> A■tab■between■each■word

How do I deal with this?

Comment: what you can do as a workaround is explicitly define a "tab" variable, like tab = "[4 literal spaces]", and then just concatenate the strings like FullString = str1 + tab + str2..........textobject.textLine(FullString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, my first suggestion of adding the explicit `\t` character didn't work. I looked at reportlab's docs and it looks like they use HTML style formatting so you won't really get a an explicit tab character. Instead, in HTML you would generally use a table to get consistent spacing between words (assuming that is why you need a tab.) Here's a quick example:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table.pdf", pagesize=letter)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []

data= [['A', 'tab', 'between', 'each', 'word'],
        ['A', 'tab', 'between', 'each', 'word']]

t=Table(data)

elements.append(t)

doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: I still got the same result.

Comment: @mathiasfk Updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: Thanks, would be easier if it worked with tabs since I'm importing the text from another source, but I guess I'll have to use this matrix approach.

Comment: What's the source? If it's just a matter of removing the tabs, there are easier ways to do that.

Comment: Removing the tabs won't do it because I need the tabular format.